# Unexpected character and syntax error on wp-includes/formatting.php

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am getting an error on my WordPress website after changing the server. it's working on cPanel but not working on the AWS server.

I haven't change anything in this file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have auto theme/plugin updates enabled?

Comment: have you been making changes to files in the `wp-includes` folder? That line does not contain characters that could cause that error, it looks like you've committed the mortal sin of WP development and modified WordPress itself

Comment: @TomJNowell, No I haven't changed anything in the file. I updated the 5948 line number code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how I got this gray code on the formatting.php page. I found this code in more than 3 places.

I download the latest version of WordPress again and updated the formatting.php and It's starting working again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you haven't modified that file, this issue can be related to php version.

1. What php version are you using in cPanel and AWS ?
2. Have you tried switching to default wordpress themes ?

You can try upgrading/downgrading to the same php version you are using in cPanel and check if it works or not.

To be sure you can re-download the said file

Comment: On AWS server: 7.2  and on cPanel 7.4 version

Comment: Can you try to use same versions on both?

Comment: I changed it from 7.4 to 7.2 and it's working on the Cpanel server. haven't checked on aws.

Comment: Can you try `wp core verify-checksums` on AWS ?

Comment: Did this helped ?

Comment: No. I updated WordPress again and start working. Maybe some issue with WordPress files